# Producing a Webbapp War file - Error that parameter will be ignored

Tags: grails

I’m trying to get a Project running on Tomcat7 that requires some Plugins and is written in Grails.

Creating a -war with the command **grails prod war** results in an Error that tells me a parameter of type [java.util.List] is not supported.

Where and how can i see which parameter are Supported and why List isn’t ?

the logfile with the errors looks like this:

```
| Loading Grails 2.4.1
| Configuring classpath
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to production
| Environment set to production.
| Environment set to production..
| Environment set to production...
| Environment set to production....
| Environment set to production.....
| Packaging Grails application
| Packaging Grails application.
| Packaging Grails application..
| Packaging Grails application...
| Packaging Grails application....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 70 source files
| Warning The [listFullAccessResources] action in [VsGrantController] accepts a parameter of type [java.util.List].  Interface types and abstract class types are not supported as command objects.  This parameter will be ignored.

       List listFullAccessResources(VsUser loggedInUser, List resultsGoups) {
       ^
  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc] General error during class generation: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service due to missing dependency org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpHead
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service due to missing dependency org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpHead
  [groovyc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1083)
```

The VsGrantController.groovy looks like this

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

class VsGrantController {

    def vsAuthenticateService
    def vsGrantService

    def index = { redirect(action:list,params:params) }

    // the delete, save and update actions only accept POST requests
    static allowedMethods = [delete:'POST', save:'POST', update:'POST']

    List listFullAccessResources(VsUser loggedInUser, List resultsGoups) {

        // labels user has full access to
        def cLabels = VsLabel.createCriteria()
        def resultsLabelsFullAccess = cLabels.listDistinct {
            grants {
                and {
                    permission {
                        eq("name", 'Full')
                    }
                    or {
                        eq("accessor", loggedInUser)
                        if(resultsGoups) {
                            or {
                                for (g in resultsGoups) {
                                    eq("accessor", g)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            order("name")
        }
```

I'm kind of new to the Grails/Groovy Tomcat Webbapp Topic 
so i hope this question is not to bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning "Interface types and abstract class types are not supported as command objects." complains because your controller action has a `List resultsGoups` parameter. This is not supported.

You can extract the parameters from the implicit 'params' map or by using a [command object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects).

Something like this...

```
def listFullAccessResources(AccessResourcesCommand cmd) {
}

class AccessResourcesCommand {
    Bar loggedInUser
    List resultsGroups
}
```

Comment: Or to mark the method private in case it is an internal controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual error is

```
Unable to load class org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service due to missing dependency org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpHead
```

You need to include **httpclient.jar** in the classpath

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 
ok if i ignore the Warning and add the httpclient.jar - the error message changes to: 
`Unable to load class org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service due to missing dependency org/apache/http/HttpRequest`

Comment: ok also added httpcore.jar which fixed the Errors... but the Warning is still existing

Answer (score -2):

Change it to:

```
def List listFullAccessResources(VsUser loggedInUser, List resultsGoups)
```

and your warning will go away...